# USB Ports Malfunctioning - usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, usb-device, touch-screen

I have a Dell Latitude 7350 2-in-1 (touchscreen tablet hybrid) that is 7+ years old. I originally had installed Pop!_OS on the system, and it worked fine for months, but one day my wireless keyboard and mouse suddenly stopped working. The wireless mouse and keyboard connected fine with my other computers. I tested several other USB devices, but the only USB devices that I could get to work were flash drives, hard drives, SD card readers, and SSDs.

I have tried these devices on BOTH USB ports on my laptop, and they both don't work for select devices (but the USB devices still seem to be getting power, as they light up) and work flawlessly for other select devices.

I should mention that for the past few months, I had an intermittent issue with my hard drive not being detected on only one port, but this issue stopped happening recently.

These are some examples of devices that didn't work:

- Wired Mouse
- Wired Keyboard
- Wireless Keyboard
- Wireless Mouse
- Yubikey
- Live USBs (e.g. an Arch Linux Live USB)

And by "not working", I mean that despite lights appearing on the devices as if they were functioning as normal, they could not be used inside of the OS. I couldn't use the Yubikey, despite the yellow light show I was witness to. Some USBs did not work; these were predominantly flash drives that held live media, but there was one that held fairly normal files which didn't work on this system.

Initially thinking this was an issue with Pop!_OS, I went to the BIOS - but my mouse/keyboard did not work there, either. I installed refind and was able to boot an Arch Linux installation I had installed on an external SSD. It is, in fact, what I am typing it on now.

Storage devices seem to work fine. They are the only devices that work fine. I can transfer, play media off them, and even run an entire operating system off one of them.

The internal keyboard and touchpad attached to this laptop work fine.

I find it hard to believe that this is some sort of hardware malfunction, because I would expect USB devices to not work at all. They are fully functional for a limited set of devices. My first instinct was to call this a driver problem with the kernel, but I have the exact same issues on the most recently updated version of Arch Linux (zen 5.14) as I do on 5.8 and 5.11 for Pop!_OS.

I have even tried disabling bluetooth, as I thought that might have been causing interruption issues, but no dice.

I have also tried disabling and re-enabling the USB controllers inside of the BIOS, but as expected, nothing changed.

This is the error log from `journalctl`:

```
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct 02 12:45:39 Arch2020 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct 02 12:45:40 Arch2020 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct 02 12:45:40 Arch2020 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Oct 02 12:45:41 Arch2020 kernel: usb 1-1: device not accepting address 10, error -71
Oct 02 12:45:42 Arch2020 kernel: usb 1-1: device not accepting address 11, error -71
Oct 02 12:45:42 Arch2020 kernel: usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Similar errors recur throughout.

Output of `sudo lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Portable SSD T5
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:5680 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have searched online, but the only solutions I found were incredibly old, unrelated to my issue, or involve a fix that I can't use (enabling IOMMU on a Gigabyte motherboard; I have a dell motherboard and I don't believe it supports IOMMU).

I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I've done several firmware updates with Pop!_OS's built-in firmware upgrader...so there's that.

EDIT 2: Some devices do not light up, such as an RGB mouse. This leads me to believe that the USB controller is not pushing enough power to the ports for anything other than storage devices. Therefore, this is a hardware problem. Oh well. I tried.

Maybe one day I'll reinstall Windows 10 on this laptop just to confirm that this is a hardware issue, but that's unlikely.

Comment: I have had similar problems when I had more USB devices than I could power connected to my computer. I solved my problem by buying powered USB hubs.